# How to upload file from external storage in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-external-storage

I am using Retrofit for sending requests to server from android. I am facing problem while uploading files that reside in phone external storage. All other files are getting correctly.

Here is my code:

```
//uri = content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/
                       9016-4EF8%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FVidMerge1503671676945.mp4   

String  filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                             + File.separator 
                             + uri.getPath().split(":")[1];

//uri.getPath() = /document/9016-4EF8:DCIM/Camera/VidMerge1503671676945.mp4
//filepath = /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VidMerge1503671676945.mp4

File file = new File(filepath);
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.getName(), requestFile);

//here I got fileNotFound Exception
```

How can I get this file correctly?

Comment: Use the uri directly. Dont mess around with file paths.

Comment: Can you please show me an example?